# Can Gradient be controlled by Curl and Divergence in Morrey spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, measure-theory, fluid-dynamics

In $L^p(\mathbb{R}^3)$, it holds for  $1< p< \infty$ and $\mu\in C^\infty_0(\mathbb{R}^3)$,
$$\|\nabla\mu\|_p\leq C \left( \|\operatorname{div} \mu\|_p + \|\nabla\times\mu\|_p \right).$$
So, how about in $\bar{M}^p(\mathbb{R}^3)$, here
\begin{equation*}
\|\mu\|_{\bar{M}^p}=\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}^3,r>0}r^{\frac{-3}{p'}}|\mu|(B(x,r))<\infty,\,p'=\frac{p}{p-1}
\end{equation*}
and $|\mu|$ is the total variation of $\mu$.

Is it also right for  $1< p< \infty$,
$$\|\nabla\mu\|_{\bar{M}^p}\leq C \left( \|\operatorname{div} \mu \|_{\bar{M}^p} + \|\nabla\times\mu\|_{\bar{M}^p}\right).$$